# Battleships game Python - When playing game, No hits are recorded through the game against the computer. All are misses

Tags: python

When taking my turn to hit computers ships, no hits are recorded. I have literally tried to hit every coordinate possible but no hits at all. At the end of the game it says I won due to sinking all ships. I have tried to fix this the past few days but I seem to have hit a block wall! Please help!
I really do not know where the code is going wrong

```
import random

# Player game board
P_BOARD = [[" "] * 8 for i in range(8)]
# Computer game board
C_BOARD = [[" "] * 8 for i in range(8)]

# Ship lengths of all ships on board
SHIP_LENGTHS = [2, 3, 3, 4, 5]

# Board coordinates which will allow player to
# guess where the computers ships are located on board
board_coordinates = {
    'A': 0,
    'B': 1,
    'C': 2,
    'D': 3,
    'E': 4,
    'F': 5,
    'G': 6,
    'H': 7
}


# Game introduction
def intro():
    print("Welcome to battleships!\n")
    print("Battleships is a strategy type guessing game\n")
    print("It is played on a ruled grid (In this case 8x8)\n")
    print("You and the computer will have 5 ships each with different sizes\n")
    print("The location of the ships will be concealed from each other\n")
    print("You will take turns calling coordinates trying to sink eachothers \
ships\n")
    print("The objective of the game is to try and sink all the computers \
ships\n")
    print("When this has been achieved but either you or the computer, the game\
will be over")

    # Ships and sizes
    print("You will have the following ships in your fleet:\n")
    print("DESTROYER - 2 BOARD POSITIONS")
    print("SUBMARINE - 3 BOARD POSITIONS")
    print("CRUISER - 3 BOARD POSITIONS")
    print("BATTLESHIP -  4 BOARD POSITIONS")
    print("CARRIER - 5 BOARD POSITIONS")

    # Game legend
    print("The following is the game legend:")
    print("@ - SHIP")
    print("O - MISSED TARGET")
    print("X - HIT TARGET")


def print_board(board):
    """
    The print board function prints out the game board
    """
    print(' A B C D E F G H')
    print(' ***************')
    row_num = 1
    for row in board:
        print("%d|%s|" % (row_num, "|".join(row)))
        row_num += 1


def print_ship(board):
    """
    The print ship function will automatically print the ships
    on the board for both the player and computer while checking
    the ships fit on the board and check for any overlapping
    """
    for ship_length in SHIP_LENGTHS:
        while True:
            if board == C_BOARD:
                direction, row, column = random.choice(["H", "V"]), \
                    random.randint(0, 7), random.randint(0, 7)
                if ship_fits(ship_length, row, column, direction):
                    if not check_overlap(board, row, column, direction,
                                         ship_length):
                        if direction == "H":
                            for i in range(column, column + ship_length):
                                board[row][i] = "@"
                        else:
                            for i in range(row, row + ship_length):
                                board[i][column] = "@"
                        break
            if board == P_BOARD:
                direction, row, column = random.choice(["H", "V"]), \
                    random.randint(0, 7), random.randint(0, 7)
                if ship_fits(ship_length, row, column, direction):
                    if not check_overlap(board, row, column, direction,
                                         ship_length):
                        if direction == "H":
                            for i in range(column, column + ship_length):
                                board[row][i] = "@"
                        else:
                            for i in range(row, row + ship_length):
                                board[i][column] = "@"
                        break


def ship_fits(SHIP_LENGTHS, row, column, direction):
    """
    The ship fits function checks if ships
    placed on the board will fit
    """
    if direction == "H":
        if column + SHIP_LENGTHS > 8:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        if row + SHIP_LENGTHS > 8:
            return False
        else:
            return True


def check_overlap(board, row, column, direction, ship_length):
    """
    The check overlap function will check if any ships placed
    on the board will overlap on other ships
    """
    if direction == "H":
        for i in range(column, column + ship_length):
            if board[row][i] == "@":
                return True
    else:
        for i in range(row, row + ship_length):
            if board[i][column] == "@":
                return True
    return False


def player_input(print_ship):
    """
    The player input function allows the player to 
    input the row and column they think the computer
    ships are located whilst getting feedback for any
    wrong keys they have entered
    """
    while True:
        try:
            row = input("Enter the row of the ship 1-8: \n")
            if row in '12345678':
                row = int(row) - 1
                break
            else:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number between 1-8")
    while True:
        try:
            column = input("Enter the column of the ship A-H: \n").upper()
            if column not in 'ABCDEFGH':
                print("Enter a valid letter between A-H")
            else:
                column = board_coordinates[column]
                break
        except KeyError:
            print("Please enter a valid letter between A-H")
    return row, column


def hit_count(board):
    """
    The hit count function will count the number of hits the player
    and computer has taken
    """
    count = 0
    for row in board:
        for column in row:
            if column == "X":
                count += 1
    return count


def p_c_turns(board):
    """
    The p c turns function will go through the player
    and the computers turns while giving feedback to player
    with what happened durint their turn aswell as the computers turn
    """
    if board == C_BOARD:
        row, column = player_input(C_BOARD)
        if board[row][column] == "O":
            p_c_turns(board)
        elif board[row][column] == "X":
            p_c_turns(board)
        elif C_BOARD[row][column] == "@":
            board[row][column] = "X"
            print("You hit a ship!\n")
        else:
            board[row][column] = "O"
            print("You hit empty waters\n")
    else:
        row, column = random.randint(0, 7), random.randint(0, 7)
        if board[row][column] == "O":
            p_c_turns(board)
        elif board[row][column] == "X":
             p_c_turns(board)
        elif P_BOARD[row][column] == "@":
            board[row][column] = "X"
            print("You ship was hit!")
        else:
            board[row][column] = "O"
            print("They hit empty water")


def start_game():
    """
    Start game function
    """
    print('COMP 1')
    print_board(C_BOARD)

    print('PLAYER 1')
    print_board(P_BOARD)

    print_ship(P_BOARD)
    # Players turn
    while True:
        print('COMP 1')
        print_board(C_BOARD)

        print('PLAYER 1')
        print_board(P_BOARD)

        print("Guess the ship coordinates\n")
        print('PLAYER')
        print_board(P_BOARD)
        p_c_turns(P_BOARD)
        if hit_count(P_BOARD) == 17:
            print("You sunk all their ships! You win!")
            break

    # Computers turn
        print('COMP')
        p_c_turns(C_BOARD)
        print_board(C_BOARD)
        if hit_count(C_BOARD) == 17:
            print("They have sunk all your ships! You lose")
            break


def play_again():
    """
    The play again function will ask the player
    if they want to play again after the game has ended
    """
    print("Would you like to play again?\n")
    answer = input("Enter Y or N \n").upper()
    print(' ')
    while True:
        if answer == "Y":
            intro()
        elif answer == "N":
            print(' ')
            print("Goodbye! See you next time!")
            print(' ')
            return False
            intro()
        else:
            print(' ')
            print("Pleas enter Y or N")
            answer = input("Enter Y or N \n").upper()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    intro()
    start_game()
    play_again()
```

Comment: Without looking at the code: If you win because you have sunk all ships, but never hit a thing, that raises a question! Were there any ships to begin with? Are you sure placement of ships at the beginning is actually happening?

Answer (score 1):

Having a look at your code, you intend to use the `print_ship()` function for adding ships onto a board, and `print_board()` to actually output a board. Here are a few things I noticed:

---

##### 1) Adding ships to the opponent's board

In the `start_game()` function, while you added the ships for the player (on line 220: `print_ship(P_BOARD)`), you have yet to do so for the opponent.

So start by adding `print_ship(C_BOARD)`.

---

##### 2) Hiding the opponent's ships

After adding the opponent's ships, the game will currently make them visible to the player. While this is good for testing purposes, you would later need to change the `print_board()` function to have them hidden from the player's view.

Here is a possible solution:

```py
def print_board(board):
    """
    The print board function prints out the game board
    """
    print('  A B C D E F G H')
    print(' *****************')
    row_num = 1

    for row in board:

        # Construct string to be printed
        row_str = "%d|%s|" % (row_num, "|".join(row))

        # If the board belongs to the computer, hide the ship positions.
        if board is C_BOARD:
            row_str = row_str.replace('@', ' ')

        # Output the row    
        print(row_str)
        row_num += 1
```

(As a side note, I recommend using `is` rather than `==` to identify boards throughout your code. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133024/21283023).)

---

##### 3) Targeting the correct board

In the while loop of `start_game()` (lines 222 - 243), the boards are mixed up. When it should be the player's turn, you should pass the opponent's board, not the player's (and vice versa).

This is why they give *you* the win when the opponent sinks all of your ships.

Consider changing `start_game()` to this:

```py
def start_game():
    """
    Start game function
    """

    # Add the ships to each board
    print_ship(P_BOARD)
    print_ship(C_BOARD)
    
    # Display the player's initial board
    print('PLAYER 1 BOARD')
    print_board(P_BOARD)
    
    # The game loop
    while True:

        # --- Player's turn ---
        print("Guess the ship coordinates\n")
        
        # Show the computers's current board (ships hidden)
        print('COMP 1 BOARD')
        print_board(C_BOARD)
        # Carry out the player's turn, targeting the computer's board.
        p_c_turns(C_BOARD)

        # If all the ships on the computer's board have been sunk, the player wins.
        if hit_count(C_BOARD) == 17:
            print("You sunk all their ships! You win!")
            break

        # --- Computers turn ---
        print('PLAYER BOARD')
        # Carry out the computer's turn, targeting the players's board.
        p_c_turns(P_BOARD)
        # Show the state of the player's board after the opponent's move.
        print_board(P_BOARD)

        # If all the ships on the player's board have been sunk, the player loses.
        if hit_count(P_BOARD) == 17:
            print("They have sunk all your ships! You lose")
            break
```

---

Snippet of the game being won by the player:

```
Guess the ship coordinates

COMP 1 BOARD
  A B C D E F G H
 *****************
1|X|X|X|X|X|O| | |
2| | |O| |O| |O| |
3| |O| | | | | | |
4|O| | | |O| | |O|
5|X| | |O|O| |X|X|
6|X|O| |O|X|O|X|X|
7|X|O|O|O|X|O|X|O|
8|O| |O| |X| | | |
Enter the row of the ship 1-8:
8
Enter the column of the ship A-H:
G
You hit a ship!

You sunk all their ships! You win!
```